# call_user_func_array error and mysqli_stmt_execute error

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong and why i keep getting these errors

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in `C:\xampp\htdocs\test-site\php\include\dataFunc.inc` on line *37*
>   Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\dataFunc.inc on line *38*

I have checked and read the php doc and `$smt` is an objected returned by `mysqli_prepare`, but here is my function:

```
function storeData($form_data, $table_name, $cxn){
if(!is_array($form_data)){
    return false;
    exit();
}
$types = str_repeat("s", count($form_data));
$params = array();
$params[] = &$types;
$keys = array_keys($form_data);
$values = array_values($form_data);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
    $params[] = &$values[$i];
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name (" . implode(',', $keys) . ") VALUES (" .
    implode(',', array_fill(0, count($values), '?')) . ")
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ";
$updates = implode(',', array_map(function($col) {
    return "$col = VALUES($col)";
}, $keys));
$sql .= $updates;

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($cxn, $sql);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
return mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Edited: Here is what my sql query is returning:

```
$sql"INSERT INTO interest 

(Baseball,Basketball,Camping,Canoeing,Cycling,Football,Gaming,Golf,Hiking,Parks,Photography,Runway,Skydiving,Soccer,Username) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Baseball = VALUES(Baseball),Basketball = VALUES(Basketball),Camping = VALUES(Camping),Canoeing = VALUES(Canoeing),Cycling = VALUES(Cycling),Football = VALUES(Football),Gaming = VALUES(Gaming),Golf = VALUES(Golf),Hiking = VALUES(Hiking),Parks = VALUES(Parks),Photography = VALUES(Photography),Runway = VALUES(Runway),Skydiving = VALUES(Skydiving),Soccer = VALUES(Soccer),Username = VALUES(Username)"
$stmt?
$table_name"interest"
$types"sssssssssssssss"
$updates"Baseball = VALUES(Baseball),Basketball = VALUES(Basketball),Camping = VALUES(Camping),Canoeing = VALUES(Canoeing),Cycling = VALUES(Cycling),Football = VALUES(Football),Gaming = VALUES(Gaming),Golf = VALUES(Golf),Hiking = VALUES(Hiking),Parks = VALUES(Parks),Photography = VALUES(Photography),Runway = VALUES(Runway),Skydiving = VALUES(Skydiving),Soccer = VALUES(Soccer),Username = VALUES(Username)"
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend PDO for dynamic query building / binding as it can accept an array of parameters.

Comment: Also, your `mysqli_prepare` is failing and returning boolean `false`. That means your query cannot be prepared because it is syntactically incorrect. I suggest you `var_dump($sql)` and add the results to your question

Comment: @Phil im sending serialized data its like 18 keys

Comment: @Phil I have added the $sql dump

Comment: Pop this at the top of your code ~ `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. You'll get an exception with some details on why your statement cannot be prepared.